# Signal smoothing algorithm (Matlab's moving average)

Tags: matlab

I have written a simple code that performs a 3-point moving average smoothing algorithm. It is meant to follow the same basic algorithm as Matlab's smooth(...) function as described [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html#bq_6ys3-1).

However, the result of my code is very different from that of Matlab's. Matlab's 3-point filter appears to perform a much more aggressive smoothing.

Here is a comparison of a noisy data smoothed using my code (red) and Matlab's function (blue):

[image: Here is a comparison:]

Here is my code written in the form of a function:

```
function [NewSignal] = smoothing(signal)
NewSignal = signal;
for i = 2 : length(signal)-1
    NewSignal(i,:) = (NewSignal(i,:)+NewSignal(i-1,:)+NewSignal(i+1,:))./3;
end
end
```

Matlab's function is used as follows:

`signal = smooth(time, signal, 3, 'moving');`

As far as I understand Matlab's function works the same way; it averages 3 adjacent bins to a single bin. So I expected both algorithms to produce the same results.

So, what is the reason for the discrepancy? And how could I tweak my code to produce the same results?

Edit:

My sample data can be found [here](http://www.filedropper.com/ds0009). It can be accessed using:

```
M = csvread('DS0009.csv');
time = M(:,1);
signal = M(:,2);
```

Here is the new result (red plot) using rinkert's correction:

[image]

Comment: you could use matlabs `filter` function with the parameter `b = ones(3,1)/3` and `a=1` in the following way `filter(b,a,signal)` to apply a moving average filter of length 3;

Comment: But shouldn't Matlab's smooth function with a span of 3 also perform the same thing? It seems like Matlab uses a larger span than what you actually specify.

Comment: comparing the results of `filter` and `smooth` you will observe that they mainly differ in the endpoints and a delay (for this also read the help of `smooth` "Because of the way endpoints are handled, the result differs from the result returned by the `filter `´function"). Try it yourself and you will see that besides these differences the responses are quite similar.

Comment: Don't these functions perform the same arithmetic as my code? That's what they say in the documentation for these functions, yet they produce a very different result.

Comment: Using a convolution will give you the same result: `xfilt = conv(x,ones(1,3),'same')./conv(ones(1,length(x)),ones(1,3),'same')` noticed that `xfilt = conv(x,ones(1,3),'same')./3` will produce the same result but will include an unwanted border effect

Comment: There's more going on here than you're sharing. For example, your blue line is the same as the red line (after Rinkert's corrections) in the first period, it gets smoothed more later. This is most likely user error. Please post the simplest code you can to reproduce your figure, see [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One reason for the difference could be that you are partially using your smoothed signal during smoothing. In your loop, you store the smoothed value in `NewSignal(i,:)`, and for the next sample to smooth this value will be called by `NewSignal(i-1,:)`.

Let `NewSignal` be determined by the original `signal` only:

```
function [NewSignal] = smoothing(signal)
    NewSignal = signal;
    for i = 2 : length(signal)-1
        NewSignal(i,:) = (signal(i,:)+signal(i-1,:)+signal(i+1,:))./3;
    end
end
```

---

**Update:** To show that the function above in fact does the same as Matlab's `smooth` function, let's consider this [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
t = (0:0.01:10).';      % time vector 
y = sin(t) + 0.5*randn(size(t));

y_smooth1 = smooth(t,y,3,'moving');
y_smooth2 = smoothing(y);

difference_methods = abs(y_smooth1-y_smooth2);
```

So creating a sine wave, add some noise, and determine the absolute difference between the two methods. If you take the sum of all the differences you will see that this adds up to something like 7.5137e-14, which cannot explain the differences you see.

Plotting the smooth signal (blue original, red smoothed):

```
figure(1); clf; hold on
plot(t,y)
plot(t,y_smooth2)
```

[image]

And then plotting the difference between the two methods:

```
figure(2); clf; hold on;
plot(t,y_smooth1-y_smooth2)
```

[image]

As you can see, the difference is of the order 1e-16, so influenced by the Floating-point relative accuracy (see [`eps`](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eps.html)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. But this is not the issue. When I use your code I still get more or less the same result as before. It is as if Matlab's 3-point smoothing function uses a much larger span than the supposed 3.

Comment: @Merin: No, I don’t buy that you get the same result as before. I also think that your blue plot is your result, and not the red. Your code smooths too much, not too little.

Comment: @Merin see the update, as you can see the difference you see is not caused by the difference in smoothing functions, but has to be something else. You should show a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to pinpoint what exactly is going wrong with your code.

Comment: @CrisLuengo No, the red plot is my result, the blue line is Matlab's function. I have included my sample data so you could verify that if you wish. When I use the code with rinkert's correction, there is only a very minuscule difference. Compared to the corrected code, the old code oversmooths but not by much. As you can see from the picture above, the difference is hardly noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question in the comments: the Function `filter` and `smooth` perform arithmetically the same (in the case that they are applied for moving average). however, there are the special cases at the beginning and endpoints which are handled differently. 
This is also stated in the documentation of smooth "[Because of the way smooth handles endpoints, the result differs from the result returned by the filter function.](https://de.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smooth.html)"

Here you see it in an example:

```
%generate randonm data
signal=rand(1,50);

%plot data
plot(signal,'LineWidth',2)
hold on
%plot filtered data
plot(filter(ones(3,1)/3,1,signal),'r-','LineWidth',2)
%plot smoothed data
plot( smooth(signal,3,'moving'),'m--','LineWidth',2)
%plot smoothed and delayed
plot([zeros(1,1); smooth(signal,3,'moving')],'k--','LineWidth',2)
hold off
legend({'Data','Filter','Smooth','Smooth-Delay'})
```

[image: Example]

As you can see the filtered data (in red) is just a delayed version of the smoothed data (in magenta). Additionally, they differ in the beginning. Delaying the smoothed data results in an identical waveform as the filtered data (besides the beginning). As rinkert pointed out, your approach overwrites the data points which you are accessing in the next step. This is a different issue.

In the next example you will see that rinkerts implementation (smooth-rinkert) is identical to matlabs `smooth`, and that your approach differs from both due to overwriting the values:

[image: comparison between your and rinkerts approach]

So it is your function which low passes the input stronger. (as pointed out by Cris)